# My 4x4 parallel multiplier outputs are all x, just like the inputs

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, modelsim

I'm new to Verilog and I am using ModelSim to compile and simulate.
Here is my code for code for PM:

```
module PM(X, Y, p);

input [3:0] X,Y;
output [7:0] p;

wire [3:0] s0_in, s1_in, s2_in, s3_in, s4_in;
wire [3:0] c0_in, c1_in, c2_in, c3_in, c4_in;
wire [3:0] x0_out, x1_out, x2_out, x3_out;

// Row1
and (x0_out[0], X[0], Y[0]);
and (x0_out[1], X[0], Y[1]);
and (x0_out[2], X[0], Y[2]);
and (x0_out[3], X[0], Y[3]);
FA fa11(x0_out[0], 1'b0, 1'b0, s0_in[0], c0_in[0]);
FA fa12(x0_out[1], 1'b0, 1'b0, s0_in[1], c0_in[1]);
FA fa13(x0_out[2], 1'b0, 1'b0, s0_in[2], c0_in[2]);
FA fa14(x0_out[3], 1'b0, 1'b0, s0_in[3], c0_in[3]);

// Row2
and (x1_out[0], X[1], Y[0]);
and (x1_out[1], X[1], Y[1]);
and (x1_out[2], X[1], Y[2]);
and (x1_out[3], X[1], Y[3]);
FA fa21(x1_out[0], s0_in[1], c0_in[0], s1_in[0], c1_in[0]);
FA fa22(x1_out[1], s0_in[2], c0_in[1], s1_in[1], c1_in[1]);
FA fa23(x1_out[2], s0_in[3], c0_in[2], s1_in[2], c1_in[2]);
FA fa24(x1_out[3], 1'b0, c0_in[3], s1_in[3], c1_in[3]);

// Row3
and (x2_out[0], X[2], Y[0]);
and (x2_out[1], X[2], Y[1]);
and (x2_out[2], X[2], Y[2]);
and (x2_out[3], X[2], Y[3]);
FA fa31(x2_out[0], s1_in[1], c1_in[0], s2_in[0], c2_in[0]);
FA fa32(x2_out[1], s1_in[2], c1_in[1], s2_in[1], c2_in[1]);
FA fa33(x2_out[2], s1_in[3], c1_in[2], s2_in[2], c2_in[2]);
FA fa34(x2_out[3], 1'b0, c1_in[3], s2_in[3], c2_in[3]);

// Row4
and (x3_out[0], X[3], Y[0]);
and (x3_out[1], X[3], Y[1]);
and (x3_out[2], X[3], Y[2]);
and (x3_out[3], X[3], Y[3]);
FA fa41(x3_out[0], s2_in[1], c2_in[0], s3_in[0], c3_in[0]);
FA fa42(x3_out[1], s2_in[2], c2_in[1], s3_in[1], c3_in[1]);
FA fa43(x3_out[2], s2_in[3], c2_in[2], s3_in[2], c3_in[2]);
FA fa44(x3_out[3], 1'b0, c2_in[3], s3_in[3], c3_in[3]);


// Row5
FA fa51(s3_in[1], c3_in[0], 1'b0, s4_in[0], c4_in[0]);
FA fa52(s3_in[2], c3_in[1], c4_in[0], s4_in[1], c4_in[1]);
FA fa53(s3_in[3], c3_in[2], c4_in[1], s4_in[2], c4_in[2]);
FA fa54(1'b0, c3_in[3], c4_in[2], s4_in[3], c4_in[3]);

assign p = {s4_in[3], s4_in[2], s4_in[1], s4_in[0], s3_in[0], s2_in[0], s1_in[0], s0_in[0]};

endmodule
module FA(x_in, y_in, c_in, s_out, c_out);
// This module is to simplify the multiplier module using a full adder.

input x_in, y_in, c_in;
output c_out, s_out;

wire w1, w2, w3;

xor(w1, x_in, y_in);
xor(s_out, w1, c_in);
and(w2, w1, c_in);
and(w3, x_in, y_in);
or(c_out, w2, w3);

endmodule
```

And here is my simplest testbench

```
module tbPM();

reg [3:0] X, Y;
wire [7:0] p;

  // Instantiate the PM module
PM dut (
X, Y, p
);


initial begin
#30;
X = 6; // 6 in binary
Y = 2; // 2 in binary

end

endmodule
```

Am I missing something important?

Comment: I've just tried running in ModelSim, and get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IMaU.png). After the 30 (ns in my case) delay at the start of your initial block, you appear to get the correct result (6 x 2 = 12)

Comment: Thanks, Tom! Guess my modelsim version is way too old.

Comment: I wonder if it failed to compile part of the code, or was using a cached old version (can happen sometimes). Try running Compile All and simulate again.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To see non-x results, you need to run the simulation for a longer time.  Add a delay in your testbench after you drive your inputs.  For example:

```
initial begin
    #30;
    X = 6; // 6 in binary
    Y = 2; // 2 in binary
    #30;
end
```

In the testbench, you declared `X` and `Y` as `reg` type, which default to unknown (x) at simulation time 0.  Then you didn't assign them known values until time 30.  The simulation ended at time 30 because there were no more events left to simulate.  With the added delay, the sim ends at time 60, leaving plenty of time to view the non-x inputs/output in your waveforms.

Comment: I think my modelsim went wrong somehow. I have Reinstalled it and finally saw the correct wave. Thank you!

Comment: @JarvisLYu1: You're welcome.  It is always good practice to add delay in your testbench _after_ your last signal changes anyway.  Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)